# Can't start localstack on macOS

Tags: python, macos, docker, amazon-s3, localstack

Using Python 3.7.10 and pip 21.1.2

Installed `localstack` by `pip install localstack`.

Ran command `localstack start` to start, got

```
WARNING:localstack.services.plugins: Service "s3" not yet available, retrying...
```

On the [document](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#running), there is a notice like

> (Note that on MacOS you may have to run TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR localstack start --docker if $TMPDIR contains a symbolic link that cannot be mounted by Docker.)

But I ran this command again:

```
TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR localstack start --docker
```

got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 102, in check_infra
    check_service_health(api=name, print_error=print_error)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 121, in check_service_health
    raise e
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 117, in check_service_health
    plugin.check(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 45, in check
    return self.check_function(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/s3/s3_starter.py", line 44, in check_s3
    assert isinstance(out['Buckets'], list)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

On the [office issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/808), somebody said remove `HOSTNAME` from environment. I didn't set it, is it the key reason?

Why this `famous` issue happened? (And always?)

---

output errors when use docker-compose

```
localstack    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
localstack    |
localstack    | Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 102, in check_infra
localstack    |     check_service_health(api=name, print_error=print_error)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 121, in check_service_health
localstack    |     raise e
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 117, in check_service_health
localstack    |     plugin.check(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 45, in check
localstack    |     return self.check_function(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/s3/s3_starter.py", line 44, in check_s3
localstack    |     assert isinstance(out['Buckets'], list)
localstack    | TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
localstack    |
localstack    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
localstack    |
localstack    | Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cli.py", line 223, in main
localstack    |     subcommand['function'](argv, args)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cli.py", line 61, in cmd_infra
localstack    |     start_infra_locally()
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/bootstrap.py", line 377, in start_infra_locally
localstack    |     return infra.start_infra()
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/infra.py", line 388, in start_infra
localstack    |     raise e
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/infra.py", line 374, in start_infra
localstack    |     thread = do_start_infra(asynchronous, apis, is_in_docker)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/infra.py", line 460, in do_start_infra
localstack    |     thread = start_api_services()
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/analytics/profiler.py", line 156, in wrapped
localstack    |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/infra.py", line 449, in start_api_services
localstack    |     check_infra(apis=apis)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 111, in check_infra
localstack    |     check_infra(retries - 1, expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, apis=apis, additional_checks=additional_checks)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 111, in check_infra
localstack    |     check_infra(retries - 1, expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, apis=apis, additional_checks=additional_checks)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 111, in check_infra
localstack    |     check_infra(retries - 1, expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, apis=apis, additional_checks=additional_checks)
localstack    |   [Previous line repeated 7 more times]
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 109, in check_infra
localstack    |     raise e
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 102, in check_infra
localstack    |     check_service_health(api=name, print_error=print_error)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 121, in check_service_health
localstack    |     raise e
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 117, in check_service_health
localstack    |     plugin.check(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/plugins.py", line 45, in check
localstack    |     return self.check_function(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
localstack    |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/s3/s3_starter.py", line 44, in check_s3
localstack    |     assert isinstance(out['Buckets'], list)
localstack    | TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
localstack    |
localstack    | ERROR: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
localstack    | (. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start --host)
localstack    | make: *** [Makefile:55: infra] Error 1
localstack    | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack    | Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
localstack    | 2021-10-06 06:09:13,229 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
localstack    |
localstack    | LocalStack version: 0.12.12
localstack    | LocalStack Docker container id: 388ad2388117
localstack    | LocalStack build date: 2021-06-07
localstack    | LocalStack build git hash: ea4dcf40
```

Comment: Is `famous` really code or a filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, You can start localstack using docker-compose. Create **docker-compose.yml** file as given below and use this command **docker-compose up** to  get started with localstack perfectly. Once localstack is up and running, you can also check the health of all the services by hitting url as **http://localhost:4566/health**

Prerequisites:

- Have Docker installed, if you haven’t already.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    hostname: localstack
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,sqs,cloudformation,iam,cloudwatch
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=false
      - LAMBDA_REMOVE_CONTAINERS=true
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
networks:
  test-net:
    external: false
    driver: bridge
    name: test-net
```

[Follow this guide to know more](https://betterprogramming.pub/dont-be-intimidated-learn-how-to-run-aws-on-your-local-machine-with-localstack-2f3448462254)

Comment: Thank you. I can run the stack on mac by this way now. But s3 and sqs services still have some Type issues. Other services can be confirmed as running.

Comment: What's the status here http://localhost:4566/health for s3 and sqs. Can you please share the error logs as well ?

Comment: Their status is `starting`. From the docker-compose's logs, I found some errors and added them to the below of the question.

Comment: Can you please remove 'hostname: localstack' from docker-compose.yml file and then try running docker-compose up and see if it works.

Comment: I tried it. But it got the same error.

Comment: For me, its working perfectly fine with the same config.